# multiple data search with same ID in excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Highlighted  is the this photo [Worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXPMX.png) are the data with the same identification but has distinct data in one of the column. In Code below i was able to search one of the data in the same identification but it will not show in my form. [UserForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zksc5.png). What I wanted needed is to show the 2 different datas with the same RF Number when I click the search button.

VBA Code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long

x = Sheets("ONGOING").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
For y = 1 To x
If Sheets("ONGOING").Cells(y, 1).Text = TextBox1.Value Then
TextBox1.Text = Sheets("ONGOING").Cells(y, 1)
TextBox2.Text = Sheets("ONGOING").Cells(y, 3 )
TextBox3.Text = Sheets("ONGOING").Cells(y, 5)
TextBox4.Text = Sheets("ONGOING").Cells(y, 8)
TextBox5.Text = Sheets("ONGOING").Cells(y, 9)
TextBox6.Text = Sheets("ONGOING").Cells(y, 6)
TextBox7.Text = Sheets("ONGOING").Cells(y, 7)
ComboBox1.Text = Sheets("ONGOING").Cells(y, 4)
ComboBox2.Text = Sheets("ONGOING").Cells(y, 2)
End If
Next y

End Sub
```

Comment: English isn't my native language either but your text is really hard to follow. Sorry for being blunt! Please try to be clearer what your problem is. As far as I understood you probably should have a look at the [Range.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) and [FindNext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext) methods.

Comment: I want to search multiple data in my workbook using vba userform with the same id/rf # but my macro only shows one data in vba form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fast solution without for loop. It will actually go round on each click - e.g. if you have 3 items for same RF# it will show you 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3... and so on on each click.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'we set the cell from where we start the search as static - 
'it keeps its value even after the macro has ended.
Static varFoundCell As Variant 
Dim rSource As Range 'declaring ranges just to make it clearer
Dim rTarget As Range

Set rSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ongoing").Range("A1").CurrentRegion

'if cell is empty it means the previous search did not give a result - so we start looking from the first cell again.
If IsEmpty(varFoundCell) Then Set varFoundCell = rSource.Cells(1, 1) 

'we looking for RF# in the first column of the source range and return the cell where it is found
Set rTarget = rSource.Columns(1).Find(TextBox1.Text, varFoundCell, LookIn:=xlValues)

'if we found it then we assigne the cell it is in as the cell we start our next search from
If Not (rTarget Is Nothing) Then Set varFoundCell = rTarget

'we found the cell, we get its row to take outher data from the source range
TextBox2.Text = rSource(rTarget.Row, 2)
'the rest of controls go here below

End Sub
```

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vj17saaq1mzxy6p/RF_TRACKER.xlsm?dl=0         
can u help me as well for update button after we search the item and found it

Answer (score 0):

maybe you needed this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim found As Boolean ' add a boolean variable

    With Sheets("ONGOING")
        x = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For y = 1 To x
            If .Cells(y, 1).Text = TextBox1.Value Then
                If Not found Then ' if first matching RF
                    found = True ' mark current RF as already found at least once
                    TextBox1.Text = .Cells(y, 1)
                    TextBox2.Text = .Cells(y, 3)
                    TextBox3.Text = .Cells(y, 5)
                    TextBox4.Text = .Cells(y, 8)
                    TextBox5.Text = .Cells(y, 9)
                    TextBox6.Text = .Cells(y, 6)
                    TextBox7.Text = .Cells(y, 7)
                    ComboBox1.Text = .Cells(y, 4)
                    ComboBox2.Text = .Cells(y, 2)
                Else 'otherwise
                    TextBox3.Text = TextBox3.Text & "," & .Cells(y, 5) 'update items list textbox
                End If
            End If
        Next y
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/vj17saaq1mzxy6p/RF_TRACKER.xlsm?dl=0] kindly check the file its still only search for one data